# How does a decrease in free Ca2+ result in nerve/muscle overexcitability?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, neuroscience, physiology, neurophysiology

I have in my notes that a decrease in free Ca2+ increases membrane permeability to Na+ so that it is brought closer to threshold, but no further details. So how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the Voltage Gated Channels,they are closed in resting state because Ca2+ is bound to it.So,in the resting stage,Ca2+ somewhat blocks the Na+ - K+ channel.But since there is low Ca2+ so there won't be much Ca2+ for guarding of channels and so it will lead to an increase in permeability.See the photo and imagine the gate being guarded by a Ca2+.I hope this helps.[image: See the photo and imagine the gate being guarded by a Ca2+ ion.]